# How to Obtain Random Samples of Particular Groupings of Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have thousands of rows of data. Two of these columns are called Area and Sub Area. Each Area has about 4, 5 or more Sub Areas.

I want to select a random sample of records like a Top 10 for each Area and Sub Area but can't think how to do this efficiently or quickly.

I have considered doing a `UNION` selecting each Area and Sub Area each time but i would have to do 120 `UNION` statements this way as there are 120 rows of distinct Areas and Sub Areas.

The same issue prevails when I considered doing `Case` statements in the `SELECT` list.

I thought perhaps I could use a `CTE` or `WHILE LOOP` in some way but not having much luck. Could making use of Window functions be something to use here?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like following to pick random 10 records for each subarea.

```
select * 
from   (select *, 
               row_number() 
                 over( 
                   partition by subarea 
                   order by newid()) RN 
        from   yourtable) T 
where  rn <= 10
```

In above query `order by newid()` will give you random records and `partition BY subarea` will generate different rownumber for each subarea.

Comment: Thanks PSK this gave me exactly what i wanted.